# Notify user if data has changed since page loaded

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have 3 users that can view and commit changes to a database.
Let's take for example an app called "personel". These 3 users can view the list of personel, edit personel data, and remove personel entries, from custom views.
I am trying to solve this scenario:

1. User A goes to /view_personel_list/
2. User B goes to /edit_personel/3/, and saves changes.
3. User A is still viewing the non-updated personel list.

I know this could be solved using AJAX, but I do not want to refresh. I am looking for a way to notify User A that the database has been changed.

Comment: look into websockets and use javascript callback to modify your data

Answer (score 1):

I am developing an app that has the same exact problem, the way i have resolved it is to use [Django-Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which allows sending notifications on object saves that can effect other users of the site

to prevent refreshes i chose to store the data being viewed in an iframe so i only refresh the iframe on a notification from channels